# Can I return a list of maps in thrift?

Tags: java, php, thrift, thrift-protocol

I am trying to return a array of hashmaps from Java to php.
What I want in php is this :
`Array :

[0] =>

  ['abc'] = "blah blah abc"

  ['def'] = "blah blah def"

  ['ghi'] = "blah blah ghi"

[1] =>

  ['abc'] = "blah blah pqr"

  ['def'] = "blah blah stu"

  ['ghi'] = "blah blah xyz"`

What is the best way to do it through `Java <=> thrift <=> php` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
I've done like this so far :

my Thrift file :

`namespace java lserver.gen

service LuceneServer {

   list<map<string,string>> search(1:string term)

}`

in Java I return an ArrayList like so :
`HashMap<String, String> res = new HashMap();`
`ArrayList<HashMap> result = new ArrayList<HashMap>();

//blah blah blah

return result;`

So in php I can access as mentioned in question...

But certainly I've no idea if that is the most efficient way of doing this...